# cmd ubuntu заменяет русские буквы на ?.Как это починить?

Tags: java, linux, ubuntu

строка вида `String str = "aбв"` превращается в ???.
Думаю это как то связанно с кодировками переводил в utf-8 и utf-16. В utf-8 тоже самое ,а в utf-16 китайские символы

Comment: Вы меняли кодировку в самом терминале?

Comment: Была такая проблема с при подключении к удаленному серверу. Исправил с помощью `locale`. Не помню точно что сделал, вроде бы просто установил другую кодировку. Попробуйте сначала так: `export LC_ALL=ru_RU.UTF-8`;

Comment: спасибо, помогло)